# How can I set up my ethernet on a fresh install of Fedora Server 23?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, ethernet, ifconfig

I am using Fedora Server 23, and cannot get my ethernet connection to work.  It works fine on Ubunutu, OS X, and Windows 7 on the same machine.

```
[root@localhost etc]# ifconfig
ens5: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

etc...

```
[root@localhost etc]# route add -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 0.0.0.0 gw 192.168.1.1 ens5
SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable
[root@localhost etc]# route add -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 0.0.0.0 gw 192.168.1.254 ens5
SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable
```

with the default route settings, pings to anything outside my LAN fail.

What can I do to test this further?

```
lspci -nnk
```

outputs:

```
...
0c:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8058 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller [11ab:436a] (rev 13)
Subsystem: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. Imac 8,1 Wired Ethernet Adapter [11ab:00ba]
Kernel driver in use: sky2
Kernel modules: sky2
...
```

Comment: what is the output of `lspci -nnk`? please.

Comment: I am interested too. iMac 7,1 2007 here :-) Same problem. Recent distribution, old ethernet controller, and thus incompatible recent driver. By default the interface used on the mac was a sub-interface named `ens5:0`.